# How do I execute a dispatchQueue.main block before another. Swift 3

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

My app is unresponsive while animation in DispatchQueue.main is playing, I understand this is due to the main thread being blocked. Is there a way around that

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.alert(text: "Hello")
}
```

My animation takes 6 seconds so it is a long time for the app being unresponsive.

My Animation:

```
func alert(text: String){
    let alert = UILabel()

    alert.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -90)
    alert.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width
    alert.frame.size.height = 45
    alert.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 114/255, green: 217/255, blue: 161/255, alpha: 0.99).cgColor
    alert.text = "\(text)"
    alert.textColor = .white
    alert.textAlignment = .center
    alert.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping // or NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    alert.numberOfLines = 0
    alert.font = UIFont (name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 17)
    alert.textColor = .white
    alert.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 203/255, blue: 147/255, alpha: 0.95).cgColor
    alert.layer.borderWidth = 2
    alert.clipsToBounds = true
    view.addSubview(alert)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        alert.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -45)
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 45
    }) { (true) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 5, animations: {
            alert.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -90)
            self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Update your question with the code causing the issues.

Comment: updated @rmaddy

Comment: It's unclear what your issue is. Your animation only takes 0.4 seconds total with a 5 second delay in the middle.

Comment: Where do you remove these alert views? It looks like you just keep adding them repeatedly, which is going to make your view hierarchy very complicated (which is a common cause of performance problems if you generate a lot of them over time).

Comment: When I call the function the alert slides down and after 5 secs it slides back up. This is not my problem however, my issue is that because it is being called in the main queue the app is unresponsive @RobNapier

Comment: Ya, in this time my app is unresponsive @rmaddy

Comment: "slides back up" does not remove the view from the view hierarchy. It's just off screen. The above code *has* to be called on the main queue; it isn't the immediate cause of your unresponsiveness. `UIView.animate` already handles keeping the main queue responsive; that's its job.

Comment: so should I remove from subview once I am done the animation? @RobNapier

Comment: `alert.removeFromSuperview()`

Comment: removing view didn't work. My app is still unresponsive while the animation is being played @RobNapier

Comment: See 0rt's answer below.

Comment: ya I tried that still freezes

Answer (score 1):

If you are using UIView.animate, you can make your application responsive by setting allowUserInteraction animation option

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 6.0, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: { 

//your animation code

}, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {}
```

or even a UIView animate.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: { 
        //show loading
    }) { (completed) in
        //hide loading
    }
```

Thanks @rmaddy for the suggestion

Comment: Do not use `performSelector`. It's a very poor substitute for `DispatchQueue`.